# Symfony 3 - Use same EntityType as child entry Type in a CollectionType

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

In my symfony 3.3.2 project , I'm trying to use the parent entity as a ChildType in a embedded form in the CollectionType inside FormBuilder:

```
class PieceType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('reference' , TextType::class , array(
              'required' => true,
              ))
            ->add('designation' , TextType::class, array(
              'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('prix' , NumberType::class, array(
              'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('quantite' , NumberType::class)
            ->add('etat' )

            ->add('equivalents' ,  CollectionType::class , array(
                  'entry_type'   => PieceType::class ,
                  'allow_add' => true,
                  'allow_delete' => true,
                  'prototype' => true,
                  'attr' => array(
                     'class' => 'pieces_form-collection',
                 ),
            ))


            ->add('caracteristiques' ,  CollectionType::class , array(
                  'entry_type'   => CaracteristiqueType::class ,
                  'allow_add' => true,
                  'allow_delete' => true,
                  'prototype' => true,
                  'attr' => array(
                     'class' => 'caract_form-collection',
                 ),
            ))

    }
}
```

When I use PieceType as a childType ,  the project does not work and i got white page only.
There are any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixe it by add my childType in the controller :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Piece $piece)
{
    $editForm = $this->createForm('EK\AdministrationBundle\Form\PieceType', 
    $piece);

    $form = $editForm
            ->add('equivalents' , CollectionType::class , array(
                  'entry_type'   => PieceType::class ,
                  'allow_add' => true,
                  'allow_delete' => true,
                  'prototype' => true,
                  'attr' => array(
                     'class' => 'pieces_form-collection',
                 ),
    ));

    return $this->render('EKAdministrationBundle:Piece:edit.html.twig', 
    array('edit_form' => $form->createView(), ));
}
```